# Simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, dom

I use [simple php dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). I have a link in my loaded dom which looks like this (in html):

```
<a href="...">Some const tesxt</a>
```

How can I select this object using `find` function? Maybe I can pass regular expression which looks at `a` container text? Btw, it's static(constant) text and I want to search need link refer to that text.

Comment: Why use that library when you can use PHP's native DOM?

Comment: seriousdev, about the only thing I could think of is if you had a non-supported PHP Version and were unable to update. IE PHP4 and under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the [Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) it should give you all you need to know.

```
$ret = $html->find('a');

foreach ($ret as $link) {
    if ($link->innertext == 'Someconst tesxt') {
          // do what you must.
    }
}
```

Not sure what else you are looking for, but I am not able to test the above, just put it together from reading the manual.

Comment: `outertext` returns full html string, not only link text.